# Meaning of Lebesgue integral compared to Riemann integral l

Tags: lebesgue-integral, riemann-integration

Recently I learned about Lebesgue integral as an alternative to Riemann integral when we want to integrate some classes of functions.

In the Riemann integral, in one dimesion, we can interpret it like the "area under the curve", and in higher dimension, it can be interpreted like the volume, etc.

I wonder for the functions which are Lebesgue-integrable but not Riemann-integrable, could I interpret the Lebesgue integral as "area under the curve" or "volum" ? Or should I interpret it with other meaning ?

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: You can indeed interpret it as an area... or a density...

Comment: Wheedon and Zygmund define the Lebesgue integral of a nonnegative measurable function $f$ over a measurable set $\Omega$ to be the Lebesgue measure of the region below the graph of $f$. So I think you can still interpret the integral as "measure of the region below the graph", just keeping in mind that we are using a new measure that is able to handle more difficult sets.